# Laravel - validação do campo formatado com moeda BR

Tags: laravel, validação, jquery-masked-input

Estou usando o **jQuery Input Mask** para colocar máscara em valores.

Por mais que no front-end a máscara evite que seja informado qualquer outro caractere que não sejam números, pontos ou a vírgula, é necessário validar no back-end também. Pois facilmente dá para remover o JS da página e enviar qualquer caractere no campo do valor.

Porém, a validação do Laravel só entende como número o formato com o ponto como separador de centavos.

Ou seja, se o valor informado no input com máscara for 9.999,99, não vai passar na validação. Só passaria se fosse 9999.99

Estou usando esta validação:

```
Validator::make($request->all(), [
  'valorTotal' => ['required','numeric'],
])->validate();
```

Tentei substituir a formatação 9.999,99 para 9999.99 usando com uma função que eu desenvolvi. Ela funciona bem.

Então com ValidationData() substituo o valor na request:

```
public function validationData() {
    $formatoUS = formatarValor($this->valorTotal, 'us');
    return array_merge(
        $this->all(),
        [
            'valorTotal' => $formatoUS
        ]
    );
}
```

O valor é formatado corretamente para 9999.99 e a *request* é atualizada para ele.

Mas a validação começa a aceitar valores com dois ou mais pontos seguidos (ex: 999..999, 9999....999). Ou seja, a validação fura.

Como resolver isso?

Answer (score 2):

A  melhor opção nessa estrutura que você está mandando é simplesmente substituir os caracteres antes da validação com `str_replace()`

```
$fields = $request->all();
$fields['valorTotal'] = str_replace(['.', ','], ['', '.'], $fields['valorTotal']); // Essa linha remove os '.' e substitui ',' por '.' deixando 999.999,99 foramtado como 999999.99
$validator = Validator::make($fields, [
  'valorTotal' => ['required','numeric'],
]);
if($validator->errors()){
    dd($validator->errors());
}
```

Comment: Ainda assim, a validação deixa passar valores com vários pontos.
Ex:9999......9 ou 9..9

Comment: Você está manipulando os erros no controller após a validação? Porque 9999......9 ou 9..9 não passam pelo `numeric` no laravel.

Comment: alterei o código colocando a verificação pro erros de falidação

Comment: Exatamente isso que pensei. No Laravel vários pontos não passam. Por isso achei estranho, que esta validação que vc colocou, e a que eu já tinha feito, deveriam funcionar.

Não retorna o erro nem desta forma, nem usando o método validate() no final.

Parece que acontece algo alterar qualquer coisa no original da request.

Comment: Acho que já entendi. A validação, da forma que sugeriu (e a minha também), remove os pontos primeiro e só depois troca a vírgula por ponto.

Assim, 9.999,99 vira 9999.9

Já no caso de 9999...99, na passagem pelo str_replace, já remove os pontos e não tem vírgula para tratar. Logo, 9999...99 retorna simplesmente 999999, passando na validação.

Vou pensar aqui em uma validação que trate isso e vamos ver se funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido com uma rule e expressão regular:

```
  public function passes($attribute, $value)
  {
    // verifica se está no formato 9.999.999.999,99 e quantos milhares forem necessários.
    $expressao = "/^([1-9]{1}[\d]{0,2}(\.[\d]{3})*(\,[\d]{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}[\d]{0,}(\,[\d]{0,2})?|0(\,[\d]{0,2})?|(\,[\d]{1,2})?)$/";
    return (preg_match($expressao,$value));
  }
```